# Using Ruby Selenium Webdriver can't select radio button as label and button are hidden

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've had a hard look around the internet to figure this out but I can't.

Trying to create an automated test for an existing website (therefore I cannot edit the website css/html/etc.). 
I want to select a radio button on a form, however, I get the "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" error message when i run the .rb file in command line.

It seems that the radio button and its label are out side the "p" and therefore not visible, which means I can't seem to click it. Even when I hover over the element with my mouse, the hand pointer is not displayed, showing it doesn't become visible on mouse over.

I have tried wait() but the website doesn't seem to be waiting to load in order to display the button.
There are no other elements that contain the same id so no duplicates. Only seems to become active when I physically select the button.
Code is as follows for the radio button on the website (I've changed some names cause of long names/ids etc):

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <p>Where the description is.</p>
    <p>Please select from the following options</p>
    <input id="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_Contacted" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateProposalWizard$ContactedAnswer" value="Contacted">
    <label for="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_Contacted"> Yes</label>
    <p>Contacted</p>
    <input id="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_NotContacted" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateProposalWizard$ContactedAnswer" value="NotContacted"><label for="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_NotContacted"> No</label>
    <p>Not Contacted</p>
    <input id="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_NotApplicable" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateProposalWizard$ContactedAnswer" value="NotApplicable">
    <label for="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_NotApplicable"> Not Applicable</label>
    <p>Not Contacted</p>

    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateProposalWizard$btnPreviousNoExact2" value="Previous" id="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_btnPreviousNoExact2" class="btn btn-sm btn-success strong">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateProposalWizard$btnContinueNoExact2" value="Continue" id="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_btnContinueNoExact2" class="btn btn-sm btn-success strong">
</div>
```

The CSS that seems to be applied for the label:

```
background-image: url("....PNG")
background-repeat: no-repeat
box-sizing: border-box
color: rgb (99, 105, 115)
cursor: default
display: inline-block
font-family: arial
font-size: 12px
font-weight: normal
line-height: 17px
margin-bottom: 5px
margin-top: 3px
padding: 0px 17px 0px 17px
text-align: left
white-space: normal
-webkit-user-select: none
```

CSS for the input:

```
...
-webkit-appearance: radio
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical
-webkit-user-select: text
```

I am using Ruby but I am not using python, javascript, java, or any other language just Ruby selenium webdriver. My code is as follows:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser.get "http://webiste.com"
browser.find_element(id: "MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_NotApplicable").click
```

The error code I receive:

```
[remote server] file:///C:/Users/SOPHIE~1.MOR/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20160523-14328-tmuf3p/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092:in `fxdriver.preconditions.visible': Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/SOPHIE~1.MOR/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20160523-14328-tmuf3p/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_'
    from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/SOPHIE~1.MOR/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20160523-14328-tmuf3p/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
    from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/SOPHIE~1.MOR/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20160523-14328-tmuf3p/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
    from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/SOPHIE~1.MOR/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20160523-14328-tmuf3p/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:389:in `clickElement'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:73:in `click'
    from new_proposal.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

Any help on how to select this radio button would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're opening the page before you try to locate elements.

I served your example using node:

```
<style>
input {
    -webkit-appearance: radio
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical
    -webkit-user-select: text
}

label {
    background-image: url("....PNG");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb (99, 105, 115);
    cursor: default;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 17px;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     margin-top: 3px;
     padding: 0px 17px 0px 17px;
     text-align: left;
     white-space: normal;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
</style>
<div class="panel-body">
    <p>Where the description is.</p>
    <p>Please select from the following options</p>
    <input id="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_Contacted" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateProposalWizard$ContactedAnswer" value="Contacted">
    <label for="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_Contacted"> Yes</label>
    <p>Contacted</p>
    <input id="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_NotContacted" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateProposalWizard$ContactedAnswer" value="NotContacted"><label for="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_NotContacted"> No</label>
    <p>Not Contacted</p>
    <input id="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_NotApplicable" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateProposalWizard$ContactedAnswer" value="NotApplicable">
    <label for="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_NotApplicable"> Not Applicable</label>
    <p>Not Contacted</p>

    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateProposalWizard$btnPreviousNoExact2" value="Previous" id="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_btnPreviousNoExact2" class="btn btn-sm btn-success strong">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateProposalWizard$btnContinueNoExact2" value="Continue" id="MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_btnContinueNoExact2" class="btn btn-sm btn-success strong">
</div>
```

and was able to select the radio button using:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser.get "http://localhost:8088/test.html"

browser.find_element(id: "MainContent_CreateProposalWizard_NotApplicable").click
```

If it still doesn't work, please update your examples.  More than likely you just have a bad selector.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the examples fully to include the full radio button coding I got from inspect element. and my code for trying to click it.

Comment: @SophiePocket I updated my answer with your new examples and I had no issues selecting the radio button.  Double check your syntax and selectors. Also, if it doesn't work, provide the error message.

Comment: I use the same syntax and selectors as what I have given in the question. I have added the CSS and the error message I receive.

Comment: @SophiePocket I updated my answer to include your provided css. I literally copied and pasted what you provided and it works, so you're still not providing enough relevant information or the script you're actually using has an error in it.  I can provide the code I use to serve it if you want to try for yourself.